# Zend Database Adapter - Complex MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I have defined a function in my Navigation model that executes a query, and I was wondering if there's a more "Zendy" way of generating/executing the query.  The query I'm using was proposed by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) on [another thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481789/maintaining-updating-record-order-in-mysql/481837#481837) for setting arbitrary record order.  I tried using a prepared statement, but the values in the SIGN() function got quoted.

I'm using the PDO adapter for MySQL.

```
/**
 *
 */
public function setPosition($parentId, $oldPosition, $newPosition)
{
    $parentId = intval($parentId);
    $oldPosition = intval($oldPosition);
    $newPosition = intval($newPosition);
    $this->getAdapter()->query("
        UPDATE `navigation`
        SET `position` = CASE `position`
            WHEN $oldPosition THEN $newPosition
            ELSE `position` + SIGN($oldPosition - $newPosition)
            END
        WHERE `parent_id` = $parentId
        AND `position` BETWEEN LEAST($oldPosition, $newPosition)
            AND GREATEST($oldPosition, $newPosition)
    ");
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: By "Zendy" I mean using the abstraction that Zend provides, rather than writing a direct query, as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Zend_Db_Select` and/or `Zend_Db_Expr`, **but** if it works like it is, don't change it. There is really no need to use any of the ZF components just because they exist or to make your code more *Zendy*. Use them to solve a specific problem.

Keep in mind that every abstraction will make your code some degrees slower. Might not be much, but also might not be necessary. I can speak from my own experience from a project where we succumbed to use as many ZF components as possible, even though we could have done without and simpler. Didn't pay off and we found ourselves refactoring out a lot of them later.

Comment: Were there specific ZF components that you especially had performance issues with?

Comment: @Sonny yes, Zend_Date performed poorly for us compared to DateTime and we use it only to format dates for a certain locale now. Also, the usual suspects: PluginBroker, Zend_Loader and the ViewHelpers when used through the the __call interface. Another wrong choice was using Zend_Config for processing various XML files. It's not that it's a bad component, but in our case DOM was more appropriate and easier. I also find myself using filter_var over Zend_Filter or Zend_Validate. Just to make this clear though: I like ZF and I think it's great when used appropriately.